# Router in Node Express 4

Tags: node.js, express

This is a question on how router is handled underneath.

If I have router:

```
var router = express.Router();
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.end('router');
});
app.use('/', router);
```

If I've fetch anywhere other than `http://localhost/`, say `http://localhost/whatever` I'll get a `Cannot GET whatever`. Who is giving out this message? I think it's the router, is it correct?

Now if I add a middleware after the router.

```
app.use('/', function(req, res) {
  console.log('-------> here');
});
```

Now if I go to `http://localhost/whatever`，then the browser never gets any response back and is just hanging there waiting for stuff.

So, it means the middleware architecture knows that if another middleware is added, then router does not have the final say. And it is expecting another route with possibly another router instance to be added. But if not, then router has the final say.

Isn't that kind of inconsistent? Somehow the router, which is itself a middleware, and the app object kind of know what each other is doing? Because router behave a little differently (call next() or give out "Cannot get" message) depending on whether another middleware is added.

I kind of dig into the code I can't really tell, but it looks like the entire middleware architecture is handled by the router object. Can someone explain a bit what's going on? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure that this is router who's giving "Cannot get" message.

Each middleware and the app itself try to handle the request in the order that they are being called.
If there is no router's or app's `get` (or `post`, etc.) able to handle the request, "Cannot get" message appears.

In the first scenario (before adding a middleware after the router), router can't handle the request, so Express looks forward
to find another `app.use` or `app.METHOD`, and not finding, it shows "Cannot get" message.

In the second scenario, another `app.use` after the router does exist, so it handles the request.

Thus, as for me everything is consistent.

Hope my answer helps you, but if your vision doesn't match mine, I'm ready for discussion :P

P.S. Sorry for my English

Comment: No problem with your English. It is at least as good as mine. :) What you said would be true if no router is ever added and it still gives you a "cannot get". But that doesn't happen.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you mean that removing the router and any `app.use`, `app.get`, etc. should give "cannot get" message, right? For me, Express throws a `TypeError: Cannot call method 'handle' of undefined` in this case. I believe this is because adding at least one `app.use` or `app.METHOD` is a requirement in Express.

Comment: But I still cannot understand why you think that "cannot get" message is shown by `router`. This message usually appears if there is no suitable route or all suitable routes call `next` (see @Brandon's answer)

Comment: "cannot get" is a 404 response. "you mean that removing the router and any app.use, app.get, etc. should give "cannot get" message". Nope. Because I think it's router that's giving out the 404. Because, as you've said it as well, removing the router doesn't give 404.

Comment: If router is middleware #1, and that custom middleware I put is #2. If I only have #1, and I have a router, then if router has the final say and gives 404. Then it shouldn't matter whether I have #2 or not the behavior is not going to change. But it did!

Comment: Oh! I figure it out. You're right. The 404 is not given by the router. If I have middleware at all, or if I have only middleware #2, but have it call next() inside it, it gives out 404 as well.

Comment: Your question made me figure out too and understand a little more how Express works. Thanks :D

Answer (score 3):

You are missing one key step in your middleware.  Middleware is a chain of asynchronous functions.  Each one is called, in turn, with a reference to the next one.  The expectation is that you pass control to the next middleware in the stack when you are done, which you are *not* doing.

```
app.use('/', function(req, res) {
  console.log('-------> here');
});
```

Try this:

```
app.use('/', function(req, res, next) {
  console.log('-------> here');
  next();
});
```

What will happen then is control will get passed to the router just as it did without your middleware.  The router cannot find any routes to handle `/whatever`, so you still get a 404 not found error.

Comment: It doesn't give out "cannot get" even if I call next.

Comment: I understood it's a chain of event. It's why there is this question. First it appear that router1 has the final say and never calls next. Then it appear that router1 has pass it to the second middleware. The behavior is different depending on whether the 2nd middleware is added. This shouldn't be the case as each middleware should be unaware of whether there are any other middlewares.

Comment: Each middleware is aware of whether there *is* a next middleware, but they don't necessarily know anything about it.  They just have a reference to it.

Comment: The 404 error is not actually from the router itself, but by the error handling middleware which comes after the router.  The router, if it finds a suitable route, handles the request via the route, otherwise, dispatches control to the `next` middleware, which will be either the error handling or something that calls the error handler.

Comment: Thanks. You both are right. Thanks for the response. I check his but I mark you up. Thank you very much.